# PHP header not working for server but works perfectly fine on local host

Tags: php, header

This code below works perfectly fine when I try on my local host but when I upload it on to my server it does not work

```
$sendquery = "INSERT INTO `message` (`from`, `to`, `subject`, `date`,`message`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['UID']."', '".$toarray['Uid']."', '$subject','$d', '$message')";
$sendresult = mysql_query($sendquery);

if($sendresult)
{
    header('Location: home.php?action=inbox&success=1');

}
else
{
    header("Location: home.php?action=inbox&success=2");
}
```

Is it a problem with my server or the code?

Comment: Do you see an error after the SQL? If you echo something (like an error message) you can't change the header anymore.

Comment: is your server connecting to the same database?

Comment: I fixed your code block. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks on how to post code on stackoverflow.

Comment: it would help if you showed the actual error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the problem is the sql runs fine after the the sql runs the page does not get redirected it stays in the dame page there is no error message it just does not redirect the page but when i am on local host it redirect's the page on server it does not redirect the page it just refreshes the page

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an error in the SQL.

If you echo something (like an error message) you can't change the header anymore.

The header is send before the echo and setting the location after that has no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the problem is the sql runs fine after the the sql runs the page does not get redirected it stays in the dame page there is no error message it just does not redirect the page but when i am on local host it redirect's the page on server it does not redirect the page it just refreshes the page

Answer (score 1):

Make sure nothing in your code started output before you set the "Location" header.
Make sure you use an **absolute URL** (as required by the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30))

Sample:

```
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/Home.php');
```

If this is the case, your redirect should work.

Some common reasons why output already started:

- BOM (Byte order mark) not handled correctly
- Warning or information
- Whitespaces or any other HTML markup before your first `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: thank you the mistake was i had started output before setting the the location but is there any way less around php where i can give location even after starting the output of the page and the next doubt how is it working on local host

Comment: No. If you take a closer look at HTTP protocol you will understand that it does not make sense to send a 30x status code with a "Location: " header and still write output (HTTP body). The output is completely useless because all the browser does is requesting a new URL. You should improve your code so everything that might cause a redirection is done before you start output.

Answer (score 0):

The localhost and webserver have many differences together. I am guessing the problem to be developed on `windows` and hosted on `linux`.

Lowercase all the header string and stop the execution after it

```
header("location: home.php?action=inbox&success=2");
exit();
```

Comment: thank you
yes you are wright about the windows and linux
but i just tried with lower case it still not redirecting my server is on ubuntu 
i tried with both lower case and exit still its not redirecting the page

Answer (score 0):

Check

> var_dump($sendresult); exit();

Enable error reporting. You may have other error.
By the way

> $sendresult = 1;
>
> if($sendresult) {
>
> header('Location: home.php?action=inbox&success=1');
>
> } else {
>
> header("Location: home.php?action=inbox&success=2");
>
> }

This works fine for me.